# How to avoid loading from cache react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have placed some json files in my public folder, I thought would be a good idea to switch around things without having to build the project.

Now I am having this problem that I am changing the json but I have to do a hard reload on browser for it to pick up the changes made in json. How do I make sure these assets are not cached without having to make any change to the file's name.

I have already unregistered the service worker.

Comment: If you are asking about production setup the solution will depend on server you use to serve assets but in most cases, you would want to serve those files with "no-cache" header

Comment: I am using `fetch` to get these json files. I found that adding an option to it like `fetch('<file>.json', { cache: 'no-store' })` should prevent the browser to store a copy in the first place. I have yet to try this, on localhost it works, but localhost never had this problem.